# Do I need to dispose mobx's `autorun` instance in Dart and how?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

I am initializing an instance of a class and starting observing an array of things with `autorun`. This method returns a disposer. It appears from my experience with Typescript, I need at some point to dispose of this instance or I risk to run into memory leaks. If that's the case, what are my options in Dart? Other than a `dispose` method called on-demand, I see no other clean way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using stateful widget, you can dispose autorun at dispose method of the stateful widget. When flutter disposes the widget, your autorun will also be disposed automatically.

Comment: Does the same auto delete happens for other the whole store. Like can I use a store to handle a form data and create it locally inside an statefull widget?  Would this be efficient?

Comment: If you are using provider or riverpod to attach the stores to the widget tree, nothing happens to the stores. You don't have to delete the stores. Depending on user actions, you can reset or dispose some parts of the store. The problem with autorun is that it is like stream connection. When you are done with it, you have to close it. Otherwise, you will keep creating streams and blow up memory.